# tesseract messing up with data on image with boxes

Tags: python, tesseract

I have an image where some digits are present inside boxes [image]

I have tried a lot of variations

```
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
pytesseract.image_to_data(im, output_type=Output.DICT,lang='eng+eng_1+eng_2+por+fra+spa',config='--psm 11')
```

Still i am not able to detect "29010" correctly.
Need help how can we do that.

Comment: This is know limitation of tesseract: in case of boxes you have to give for OCR just are within box (e.g. without borders) to get correct results => you need to do custom layout analyze.

Comment: @user898678 thanks i was able to resolve this. I removed horizontal and vertical lines in pre processing.